# initialize object from template class

Tags: java

I want to initialize object from  template class 
And how to deal with it with the rest of the classes

```
public class Pair<A, B> {
    private A first;
    private B second;

    public Pair(A first, B second) {
        super();
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }


    public  A getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(A first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(B second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

public class Battleship {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pair g<int ,int>=new Pair <int,int>();//i get error here

}
```

}

/*

Comment: what template class? what classes are you trying to initialize? what have you tried?

Comment: Pair g<int ,int>=new Pair <int,int>(); //I get error here

Comment: because the constructor method requires 2 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as the syntax is wrong.

```
Pair g<int ,int>=new Pair <int,int>();
```

should be

```
Pair<Integer, Integer> g = new Pair<>(1, 2);
```

If a constructor takes two arguments, you have to provide those arguments.

Generics doesn't support primitives in Java 9, though there is a project to allow this in future versions.

Comment: how can create object to  use  void setFirst(A first) and setSecond and Getfirst()
ex:
g. setFirst(1);
g.setSecond(2);
System.out.println(g.getFirst());
?????????

Comment: You can not create object with using Get or Set methods. You should create object before using Getting or Setting methods. If you first type like this "Pair<Integer, Integer> g = new Pair<>(1, 2); " then you can use g.setFirst(1); @IssamOtoz

Comment: I want to do this 
Pair p;
p.setFirst(1);
then 
p.Getfirst();
can I do This syntax ??

Comment: If you type "Pair p" this just reference, not create object. If you want use set and get methods, you should CREATE OBJECT FIRST. @IssamOtoz

Comment: @IssamOtoz You can but this is an uninitialised **reference** to `null` not a object.

Comment: Yes  I am understand Now 
thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 0):

You are working with [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types.

When you work with generic types and want to initialize an instance of a class, you have to tell which types will be A and B.

In your case, to initialize Pair correctly, you should do the following, e.g.:

```
Pair<Integer,Integer> p = new Pair<>(1,2);
Pair<String,Integer> p = new Pair<>("Hello",2);
Pair<Integer,Character> p = new Pair<>(3,'C');
Pair<CustomClass1, CustomClass2> p = new Pair<>(new CustomClass1() ,CustomClass2());
```